# Error w/declaration on else statement (C++)

Tags: c++, if-statement, declaration

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Range of numbers, handles input in which the first number is smaller than the second.

int main()
{
    int max = 10;
    int min = 0;
    while(cin >> min)
    {
        if(min<max)
        {
            ++min;
            cout << "The number inputted is well in the RANGE: " << min << endl;
        else
        {
            cout << "The number inputted is not in the RANGE: " << max << endl;
        }
    }
} // End of if.
}
```

What's going on? Why isn't this working? I'm new to Stack so I tried posting this, er any help?

Comment: How isn't this working? Please be more precise.

Comment: If this is your actual code, look at the braces they are not matched up correctly (now that I've cleaned up your formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should end the if before you start your else part :

```
int main()
{
int max = 10;
int min = 0;
while(cin >> min){
   if(min<max){
     ++min;         //dont understand why do you do this !
     cout << "The number inputted is well in the RANGE: " << min << endl;
     } // End of if.
   else{
   cout << "The number inputted is not in the RANGE: " << max << endl;
    }
   }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works very well, I guess I overlooked that part and I thought that we didn't need to end ifs. Thanks.